# django, many to many relation get_field name

Tags: django, many-to-many

I had two django models connected with many to many relationship.

First model:

```
class Category(models.Model):

   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name='categories',
                                  blank=True, null=True,
                                  verbose_name=_('Products'),
                                  )
```

second model:

```
class Product(models.Model):

    description = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Description'), default='')
    manifactor = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Manifactor'), default='Blackberry', max_length=255)
```

ok, so:

```
product = Product.objects.all()[0]
product.categories  - give me a list of categories for this product.
```

but:

```
product._meta.many_to_many - return empty list [].
and product._meta.get_field('categories') - return None.
```

Why ?

How can I get the verbose name of category field from product object ?

Comment: I don't see this issue, I get `[<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField: field_name>]` in `._meta.many_to_many`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add

```
categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, 
                                    through=Category.products.through)
```

to your Product model

Comment: So, there is no way to get category field without changing Product model ?